# Jquery Sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#gallery").dragsort({
        dragSelector: "div",
        dragEnd: saveOrder,
        placeHolderTemplate: "<li class='placeHolder'><div></div></li>"
    });

    function saveOrder() {
        var data =  $("#gallery li").map(function() {
                        return $(this).attr("itemID");
                    }).get();
        $.post("example.php", { "ids[]": data });
    };
</script>
```

I am learning jquery , and I am eager to learn more about it, I read a tutorial out there on how to save [jquery sortable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/display-grid.html) , But i need a code where i can delete a item and have it saved using php.
I am able to make it work for one where i posted id of one particular sortable and deleted , i read about each and tried but failed :) so for more than one(automatic) it is getting troublesome for me, as i need to have id or something to save deleted in database,

I seem to be lost direction, some help can really help me sharpen my skills.

[Js Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/rigids/Wmjsr/)

Comment: Could elaborate more how do you plan to delete and what actually do you want to save: the odrder, deleted or both.

Comment: i am able to save when i am dragging but neither i am able to have delete button on all sortables nor able to save them in comma separated values. for eg if i deleted sortable3 out of 6 i want to record it as 1,2,4,5,6

Comment: DO you want to save the sate for each li ? just like in example provided by you? can you show your code so as we can help you go through it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi have a look [there](http://jsfiddle.net/kwicher/Wmjsr/3/) if it does as you wish.
K

Comment: Thanks.... I read jquery docs about the method you did it as , Thanks for teaching a girl how to do it in right manner , I was doing it with Each method but this work great and as expected.
I am also practicing collapse/uncollapsible as in [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/portlets.html) the problem i am facing is it is conflicting with delete i mean when i click delete it collapses
DO i use another button and save collapsible/uncollapsible state without conflicting

Comment: I see noreason delete and collapse should interefere if you use diferent elements for that. However if you use button for collapsing add some class to either button type and evoke the appropriate action accordingly.

Comment: I am not able to pass the elements to depict if it is collapsed or not... i.e. state of 1st box and all other boxes , can you help me with that in your fiddle...

Comment: Try to modify the jsFiddle so that I at least have idea what you want to do. I cannot really figure it out from your description.